# Restore overridden system api call

Tags: c++, linker

Working in a large code base where there is code that overrode a standard library function.

How can I get my code to call the standard library function instead of the overridden function?

Simple Example:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

extern "C"
int system(const char *syscmd)
{
    printf("Bye!\n");
}

int main()
{
    ::system("echo 'Hi'");
    return 0;
}
```

How do I get the code above to print out "Hi" instead of "Bye!"? Again, I can't change the overridden method because it is already part of a compiled object file included in the linking and there is other code that depends on the overridden behavior...

Comment: Use `std::system`?  https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/system

Comment: @NathanOliver - ok, yeah - I could also use printf or std::cout as well. I'm not asking how to invoke another function; but rather how to use the original standard library function.

Comment: It is the original, it's just inside a namespace.  `<cstdlib>` is the C++ version of `<stdlib.h>`.

Comment: Gave it a try... still didn't work. Changing the above to use std::system still resulted in "Bye!"

Comment: What OS and compiler?

Comment: linux - gcc 8.5

Comment: hmm, I wonder if an ODR violation is to blame for that behavior.

Comment: Don't tag C++ with the tag C.

Comment: @273K I'd say it is mostly C; not C++. The standard library methods have the standard C ABI signatures (hence the 'extern "C"'). If anything, c++ should be removed and C should remain... However, I didn't want to preclude c++ solutions if there were any language features within c++ that can provide a solution.

Comment: @NathanOliver - Thank you for the reference to ODR. I read up on that, and it sounds like it is what I might be running in to.

Comment: @273K The dual tagging seems appropriate here.  The root cause of the problem seems to be [undefined behavior from using a C reserved identifier](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.1.3) which then flows into ODR.  IMO this question is a good object lesson about using  a garbage-level hack and  reusing standard function names.

Comment: The syntax is C++, the tag C is inappropriate here.

Comment: That's called _refactoring._ Change every occurance of `system` to `SystemImplementationByJimWhoCouldntComeUpWithAnOriginalName`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Linux, you can use `dlsym` to get the original `system` (assuming dynamic linking).

Example:

```cpp
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

extern "C"
int system(const char *syscmd)
{
    printf("Bye!\n");
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    auto *libc_system = (decltype(system) *) dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "system");
    libc_system("echo 'Hi'");
    return 0;
}
```

```
g++ -g -Wall t.cc -ldl
./a.out
Hi
```

QED.

> I can't change the overridden method because it is already part of a compiled object file included in the linking

Another option is to use `objcopy --redefine-sym system=custom_system foo.o foo2.o` (where `foo.o` is your existing compiled object file). Using this approach you may have to link *all* objects for which you desire to use the redefined `system` into a single object first, then `objcopy` it and link it with all the other code which *doesn't* want to use the redefined `system`.